# How to preserve quotation marks in bash function?

Tags: linux, bash

The function foo is exported in .bashrc

```
foo()
{
    echo "run '$@'"
    $@
}
export -f foo
```

Works

```
foo cmake --build .
run 'cmake --build .'
[ 10%] Built target main
...
```

Does not work

```
foo cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DARCHITECTURE_TYPE=armv7_32
run 'cmake -G Unix Makefiles -DARCHITECTURE_TYPE=armv7_32'
CMake Error: Could not create named generator Unix
...
```

Comment: There's little or no reason to export the function. Any interactive shell already sources `.bashrc` itself, and there are good reasons *not* to provide such functions in non-interactive shells.

Comment: @chepner: thanks for  your hint. May be I do not yet understand the concept of non-interactive shells. Does this mean it is not possible ?

Comment: @chepner: the reason for me is to bypass a program (ib_console) which is not installed on some machines. It works fine except for those calls where exception marks are used

Comment: A non-interactive shell is typically just a shell that executes a script. You wouldn't want the script to work differently than intended because you inadvertently overrode a function the script relied on. *Defining* `foo` in `.bashrc` is fine; the `export -f foo` just isn't necessary.

Comment: @chepner: when removing the export statement from .bashrc I get the error 'command not found' ??

Answer (score 1):

There is *never* a reason to use `$@` unquoted; it's identical to `$*` otherwise.

```
foo () {
  # including $@ in a longer quoted string can cause some
  # weird side effects; I just use $* instead.
  echo "run '$*'" 
  "$@"
}
```